# Save website content into txt files

Tags: r, web-crawler

I am trying to write R code where I input an URL and output (save on hard drive) a .txt file. I created a large list of url using the "edgarWebR" package. An example would be "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1131013/000119312518074650/d442610dncsr.htm". Basically

1. open the link
2. Copy everything (CTRL+A, CTRL+C)
3. open empy text file and paste content (CTRL+V)
4. save .txt file under specified name

(in a looped fashion of course). I am inclined to "hard code it" (as in open website in browner using browseURL(...) and "send keys" commands). But I am afraid that it will not run very smoothly. However other commands (such as readLines()) seem to copy the HTML structure (therefore returning not only the text).

In the end I am interested in a short paragraph of each of those shareholder letters (containing only text; Therefore Tables/graphs are no concern in my particular setup.)

Anyone aware of an R function that would help`?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let me know incase below code works for you. xpathSApply can be applied for different html components as well. Since in your case only paragraphs are required.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

# Create character vector of urls
urls <- c("url1", "url2", "url3")

for ( url in urls) {
    # download html
    html <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE)

    # parse html
    doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
    plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)

    # writing lines to html
    # depends whether you need separate files for each url or same
    fileConn<-file(paste(url, "txt", sep="."))
    writeLines(paste(plain.text, collapse = "\n"), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
}
```

Comment: hey, I ended up using the the same codes. htmlParse is painfully slow however. arround10-15seconds for the document sizes I am using. not sure yet whether this is computationally acceptable given the ammount of filings I am trying to recover, but is does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input. Turns out that any html conversion took too much time given the ammount of websites I need to parse. The (working) solution probably violates some best-practice guidelines, but it does do the job.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path + '/codes_ml/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe') # initialize driver
# it is fine to open the driver just once

# loop over urls will the text
driver.get(report_url)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'c')
text = clipboard.paste()
```